# Angular2: limit scope to an element versus the entire page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In knockout, we can limit binding scope to a specific element on the page, as follows:

**ko.applyBindings(myVM, document.getElementById("myDiv"))**

Is it possible to do something similar in Angular2, so that the scope of Angular is not applied across an entire page, but, is instead limited to a specific div or element?

One possible solution would be to have an iFrame on the page that points to the Angular2 app, but, I'm looking for alternative (non-iFrame) options.

**Edit/Update**

As i described in the comment below, if I simply put the root app component inside of a div instead of directly in the body element, this seems to limit the scope of angular2 as well.

**Before**

```html
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

**After**

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1" style="height:200px; width:400px;">
        <my-app>Loading</my-app>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="height:300px; width:500px;">
        This is outside of the Angular App
    </div>
      
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have another potential solution.  After bootstrapping my root app module, I was adding the root app component inside the body element directly, if I instead add a div inside the body element, and then, add root app component within that div instead of inside the body element directly, this, seems to limit the scope of Angular2 to a certain degree.

Comment: What scope are you talking about? Angular2 doesn't have a scope. It has a class per component which could be seen as scope.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - You are correct, each component has its own class, template, and CSS that is associated with it.  Thus, each component is self-contained, which is why Angular2 is so appealing to me.  I am referring more to limiting Angular2 itself so that it does not take over the entire HTML page, basically to allow me to inject or include an Angular2 application as part of an html page, where the entire page is not Angular driven.  Hope that makes sense?